# cMake install third party library from subproject

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I try to setup a new cMake project which creates two libraries.
A core library *libCore.dll* which depends on additional third party libraries and de *libWrap.dll* which use the libCore library and of course require the third party libraries.

For the installation of *libCore* I added the following two install commands, which result in a folder libCore containing the library and dependencies:

```
install(TARGETS libCore
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    PUBLIC_HEADER
      DESTINATION "libCore/include"
    RUNTIME 
      DESTINATION "libCore/bin"
    RESOURCE
      DESTINATION "libCore/bin"
    LIBRARY 
      DESTINATION "libCore/lib"
    ARCHIVE 
      DESTINATION "libCore/lib"
)
install(FILES ${THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARIES}
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    DESTINATION "libCore/bin"
)
```

So far so good. Now, when I use that library in an additional target *libWrap* (in the same cMake project) I could successfully link to them and build the library. I installed that *libWrap* with the following command:

```
install(TARGETS libWrap libCore
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    PUBLIC_HEADER
      DESTINATION "libWrap/include"
    RUNTIME 
      DESTINATION "libWrap/bin"
    RESOURCE
      DESTINATION "libWrap/bin"
    LIBRARY 
      DESTINATION "libWrap/lib"
    ARCHIVE 
      DESTINATION "libWrap/lib"
  )
```

This install the *libWrap* successfully in the libWrap directory and copies also the *libCore*. Unfortunately the third party dependencies which was installed with  `instal(FILE ...)` are not installed to the libWrap directory.

Does any one know, how I could declare the third party binary to be required and automatically installed with the *libCore* target?

Thank you for any Hint!

Comment: "how I could declare the third party binary to be required and automatically installed with the libCore target?" You cannot declare things to be auto-installed. Look, you cannot make even `libCore` to be auto-installed when you install `libWrap`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was a bit inaccurate with my question. Is it possible to *append* external files to a target. So the call of ```install(FILE ...) doesn't append them to any target. Or is it possible to create a TARGET which just copies binaries when install is called?

Comment: "is it possible to create a TARGET which just copies binaries when install is called?" - No, you cannot create such target. The command `install(TARGETS)` works only with executable and libraries targets. For place all dynamic objects (an executable and `.dll`-s) into the same directory, you may look into [BundleUtilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/BundleUtilities.html). I've never used it, but according to the description it should help in your case.